# How do I getting all values from a one panda.series row that correspond to s specific value in second row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this :

```
 name   age       occ   salary
0   Vinay  22.0  engineer  60000.0
1  Kushal   NaN    doctor  70000.0
2    Aman  24.0  engineer  80000.0
3   Rahul   NaN    doctor  65000.0
4  Ramesh  25.0    doctor  70000.0
```

and im trying to get all salary values that correspond to a specific occupation ,t o then compute the mean salary of that occ.

Answer (score 1):

here is an answer with a few step

```
temp_df = df.loc[df['occ'] == 'engineer']
temp_df.salary.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

All averages at once:

```
df_averages = df[['occ', 'salary']].groupby('occ').mean()

                salary
occ
doctor    68333.333333
engineer  70000.000000
```